# merging tweets by date, returning count of sentiment score

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a sentiment analysis problem. My dataframe is as follows

```
   tweet     sentiment_score    timestamp   ticker
0   abc       3                2018-09-19   $AMD
1   def       1                2018-10-19   $AMD
2   wtf       2                2018-07-12   $PH   
3   pqr       2                2018-07-12   $PH
4   lmn       3                2018-08-23   $FB
5   jqr       3                2018-08-23   $FB
6   okm       1                2018-08-24   $FB
```

I want to

(1)Aggregate (merge) the tweets per "ticker" at a day level. So I can run a sentiment analysis and get overall sentiment score per ticker on a given day.

(2)"sentiment_score" has values {0,1,2,3,4}, I want to create 5 new columns which contain the count of no.of tweets where sentiment_score is {0,1,2,3,4} for every "ticker" at a day level.

Expected output

```
   tweet        timestamp   ticker   setiment_1 sentiment_2 sentiment_3
0   abc,def     2018-09-19  $AMD         1         0          1
2   wtf,pqr     2018-07-12  $PH          0         2          0     
4   lmn,jqr     2018-08-23  $FB          0         0          2
6   okm         2018-08-24  $FB          1         0          0
```

I tried individual groupby operations but they didn't give the required output. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you post a few more rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.pivot_table(...)`:

```py
df["_dummy"]=1
df2=df.pivot_table(index=["timestamp", "ticker"], columns="sentiment_score", values="_dummy", aggfunc="sum").fillna(0)
```

Output:

```py
sentiment_score      2    3
timestamp  ticker
2018-07-12 $AVGO   1.0  0.0
2018-07-19 $PH     1.0  0.0
2018-08-23 $FB     0.0  1.0
2018-09-19 $AMD    0.0  1.0
2018-10-09 $CAT    0.0  1.0
```

Documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html

**Edit**

If you want to also merge tweets you can do on top of the above:

```py
df3=df.pivot_table(index=["timestamp", "ticker"], columns="sentiment_score", values="stocktwit_tweet", aggfunc="sum")
#and to merge it together with previous df:
res=pd.concat([df2, df3], axis=1)
#axis=1 - merge df-s horizontally, axis=0 - merge vertically
```

Comment: This partially answers my question. But I also want to merge my tweets, how can I achieve that in the same pivot table operation?

Comment: I added part for merging tweet messages

Comment: thanks a ton mate! it worked. I used to_records to convert the pivot table back to dataframe!